# Unable to use other Desktop Environments through login in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, login, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I had Cinnamon installed and after system reboot, tried to choose Cinnamon ( currently on Unity ) through the login menu. Unfortunately, when I click the icon, the whole page text disappears and the system hangs. It looks like a CSS layout without any text. The only way out is hardware switch off and then use Unity again.

Is there any way I can choose other DE ( if installed ) through login menu, avoiding a hung system ?

Comment: You aren't going to like this, but I think it would be better if you migrated to 17.04.

Comment: I use 16.04 since it's LTS

Comment: @jack0da Why do you suggest 17.04? Do you believe that it'll fix the problem, or because it's the latest version? How would it be "better"?

Comment: Did Cinnamon ever work before, or is this the first time trying to log into it?

Comment: @heynnema If I thought it would fix ti I would've wrote an answer. This is just a suggestion because I think they might have fixed this in the next version, and partially because it is the latest version.

Comment: @heynnema It's the first time I added it since my update to 16.04 from 14.04.

Comment: I'd recommend updating to 16.04.2 and then reinstalling Cinnamon and see if that resolves the problem for you. I suspect your problem has to do with the Display Manager (LightDM, GDM, ertc) or your video drivers... but try the update and reinstall.

Comment: I think I am on the latest 16.04. How to check ? For update, sudo apt-get update ? @heynnema

Comment: @user227495 To check your version, open System Settings and choose the Details panel. If you need to update to 16.04.2, just use the `Software Updater` application.

Comment: I am on the latest. Just checked @heynnema